# Responsive scene with ngx-graph for Angular App

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi i have div with width: 1000px and height: 1000px. I putted inside this div another div with scene 5000px5000px. I want to have on bigger div navigation like on google maps(scalable on scroll). I tried with ngx-graph but i failed. There will be dynamically generated divs with drag and drop functions and lines to connect them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8LYU.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited post. I have scene like in link, it's made using ngx-graph and i can't set a space with border to stop dragging my element.